# Is possible to finish unit testing when a method is called?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, mvp

Here is my test method where It should be success if *showLoading()* and *loadDataSuccess(response)* was called:

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
     public class PresenterTest {
            @Mock  
            private ProfileContract.View view;
            @Mock
            private ProfileContract.Handler handler;

            @Test
            public void onLoadDataClicked() {
              presenter.loadData();
              verify(mView, times(1)).showLoading();
              verify(mHandler, times(1)).loadDataSuccess();
            }
     }
```

**UPDATE 1**
Here is my presenter:

```
class ProfilePresenter(private val mView: ProfileContract.View) : ProfileContract.Handler {

     override fun loadData() {
            mView.showLoading()
            mUserService.user()
                    .compose(RxUtil.mapper())
                    .subscribe({ response ->
                        loadDataSuccess()
                    }, { error ->
                        //stuff
                    })
        }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use `return` statment, your test finish with success status.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a basic problem with your test setup:

You do not use `verify` to check if one function calles another function within the same class. `Verify` is used to verify that the tested class calls function on other (*mocked*) classes. If I am not mistaken, your setup should actually give you an error message saying that you can not use `verify` on instantiated classes.

What you should do -if you want to check if `onCompleteClicked()` produces the correct results- is to check if the data that gets changed inside the `onStuffComplete()` function is set correctly. You can use an `assert` for that.

As an example, lets say `onStuffCompleted()` sets `completeCounter` to `1`

```
@Test
public void onCompleteClicked() {
  presenter.onStuffCompleteClicked();
  assertEquals(completCounter , 1);
}
```

And to answer your original question: `verify` (and `assert`) will pass if the requirements were met (and by this the whole test will pass) and fail if not. You do not need to add any additional stuff (but once again: `verify` will only work with *mocked* classes).